# Type conversions and conditional return types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, casting

I am trying to convert between custom types in TypeScript and use a conditional return type. However, TS won't let me, as the following doesn't compile:

```js
type AString = { a: string };
type ANumber = { a: number };
type A<T> = T extends string ? AString : ANumber;
function isANumber(x: any): x is ANumber {
    return x && typeof x.a === "number";
}
function isAString(x: any): x is AString {
    return x && typeof x.a === "string";
}

type BString = { b: string };
type BNumber = { b: number };
type B<T> = T extends string ? BString : BNumber;

function a2b<T>(a: A<T>): T extends string ? BString : BNumber {
    if (isAString(a)) return { b: a.a } as BString;
    if (isANumber(a)) return { b: a.a } as BNumber;
}
```

There is complaint about the lacking return at the end of the function, which TS could know, but that's not my pain point. More importantly, neither `BString` nor `BNumber` can be assigned to `T extends string ? BString : BNumber`. Even more confusingly, both cannot be assigned to `B<T>`. What did I miss about conditional types?

PS: Using a union type would solve the compiler error in this example, but not in my actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is typescript can't make the jump in logic that `isAString(a)` is equivalent to checking `T extends string`.  It narrows down the definition of the variable `a` but not of the generic `T`.  It still thinks that `T` could be either, so it complains about returning `BString` or `BNumber` individually because it doesn't know that you are returning the right one.

Your `as BString` and `as BNumber` declarations aren't actually necessary because typescript does already understand that it is dealing with `{b: string}` in the first case and `{b: number}` in the second.  The jump that it is failing to make is that these types have anything to do with `T`.

The easiest way to shut it up is to use `as B<T>` in both scenarios.

Another simple solution is to make your return type rely directly on a value which it can infer from `T`.

```
function a2b<T extends AString | ANumber>(a: T): {b: T['a']} {
    return { b: a.a };
}
```

If the generic `T` directly describes the variable `a` then typescript can make better inferences and will understand that if `a` is x than `T` must be x.  So I try where I can to make the generic apply to the whole variable.  Typescript is not the best at working backwards.

I'm still not able to get a really great solution here though.  It just does not like the `extends`. If I say that `T extends AString | ANumber` and work backwards to get `string` or `number` for the return type, defining `AType` as `T['a']` works fine, but if `AType` is `T extends AString ? string : number` then it breaks.
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAggysATgSwHYHMoF4oG8oCGAXFAM5JqYC%20A3AFCiSwByArgLYBGEi2ehJVB269aDcNBgAeACoA%20PjKgQAHsAioAJqTIUMUAPywEKfSRhsuPegDNWqAMbBkAe1RRkpC8J4AKFSQEqCAAlCQqHjreVry4dFAJUIgQwKyI7hEAZJlQjBAuNlAqAHQE2Fg4AERCMZX0VHR2js5ukfB66P6BwWFFkcYdePGJyanpfdm5EgVFpeVV5KbodXQN4kwAQiaUfPicJIs7YnlQG5Yiu1D7UDUXxxKnsgo4SqrqWjqH%20kZbgyRnPkQ9HWkhkEgAjLJlGoNNoBksoAAfFiA55QV4wj7wnZGL6YQSA4FNJyudwEABMnEhGPecPaCOR0REcl8xHRvVw1xgYMg1LkVCGCWQhV8nnplFZIRCgsSDjc5CgDgAFhAHABrPgEUr0RJJFJpdx7QJzMQJBpCkVi85%20AhSmUJUYG-jXLVlU1QBprE7ciTkqFvWFRbb6RnWxBomQAbQA5ARowBdIn2EmtCmcP00wPYkMomIstkyDlcnkQDP8mXCqCirzBzq26VxXVy1AK5WqjU4V06kb68ZGwgm7vmjyWrxhyUN4YO3uGq7Gt1D1ZAA)

It has to do with what `extends` really means and that literal strings and literal numbers extend string and number.

Take a look at the errors on this and I think you'll understand the problem:

```
function a2b<T>(a: A<T>): {b: T} {
    if (isAString(a)) return { b: a.a }; // error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
 // 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
    if (isANumber(a)) return { b: a.a };
}
```

So we know that `a.a` is a `string` and that `T extends string`, but we still don't know that `a.a` is assignable to `T` because you could have a case where `T` is the literal string `some string` and `a` is `{a: "other string"}`.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)